ng2-pdf-viewer : integration ng2-pdf-viewer in angular 17. getting error PDF.js v2.2.171
I am integration ng2-pdf-viewer in angular 17.
I am passing base64 string with starting data:application/pdf;base64,content.
I am getting below error. Please advise
PDF.js v2.2.171 (build: c8c937c2)
Message: PDFDocument: Stream must have data
undefined
;
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer   [pdfSrc]="pdfSrc"  style="display: block;">
       </ng2-pdfjs-viewer>

this.pdfSrc = ${'data:application/pdf;base64,'}${pdf}
